# react native : swiper, have an issue while display first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, swiper.js

In my code I did swiper with the "**react-native-swiper**" directory.
There is a problem that when the swiper screen is displayed then the last page jumps to the first page and stop there. (for example if I have 4 points in the swiper view then the leftmost point jumps to the rightmost)
I would love direction in solving my problem.

```
<Swiper
            scrollsToTop={true}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
            bounces={true}
            dotStyle={styles.NonActiveDot}
            activeDotStyle={styles.activeDot}
          >
            {Object.keys(groupFacilities).map((key) => (
              <SafeAreaView key={key} style={styles.safeArea}>
                <View key={key}>
                  <View style={styles.secondaryTitleView}>
                    <Text style={styles.secondaryTitleText}>{`${selectedEpicenter[0]?.EpicenterName} - ${key}`}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <FlatList
                    data={groupFacilities[key]}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.ID}
                  />
                </View>
              </SafeAreaView>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
```

Comment: I think your page in loop so you just add `loop={false}` in `<Swiper />`

Comment: Thats works ! thx